# batch explorer search file and set variable

Tags: batch-file, set

I want a bat file to open the explorer, go to a path, and select a file.

Example file is in this path, but it can always be somewhere else:

```
c:\dir1\1.so
```

So opening the Explorer:

```
%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe /e,c:\
```

and when open is I want to click to dir test and select 1.iso and set variables

```
filename = 1.iso
dirname = c:\test
```

Comment: while you can start the Explorer with batch,, (pure) batch has no possibilities to interact with it (or get any information back)

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15885132/file-folder-chooser-dialog-from-a-windows-batch-script) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22874194/directory-traversal-and-file-selection-with-bat/22875371#22875371)...

Comment: thx Aacini, working